What are the dimensions of the tensor which Eigen's extract_image_patches returns?
I am using Eigen's extract_image_patches but I am unclear about the tensor which it returns. The documentation is not particularly helpful (at least to me):

returns a tensor of coefficient image patches extracted from the input tensor, which is expected to have dimensions ordered as follows (depending on the data layout of the input tensor, and the number of additional dimensions 'N'):
ColMajor 1st dimension: channels (of size d) 2nd dimension: rows (of size r) 3rd dimension: columns (of size c) 4th-Nth dimension: time (for video) or batch (for bulk processing).
RowMajor (reverse order of ColMajor) 1st-Nth dimension: time (for video) or batch (for bulk processing). N+1'th dimension: columns (of size c) N+2'th dimension: rows (of size r) N+3'th dimension: channels (of size d)
The returned tensor has one greater dimension than the input tensor, which is used to index each patch. The patch index in the output tensor depends on the data layout of the input tensor: the patch index is the 4'th dimension in ColMajor layout, and the 4'th from the last dimension in RowMajor layout.

As I understand it, for a rank 4 input tensor which is in column major order then it would return a rank 5 tensor:

First dimension: number of channels
Second dimension: rows (I think this means rows of the patch)
Third dimension: columns (I think this means columns of the patch)
Fourth dimension: ???
Fifth dimension: ????

Is the fourth dimension the batch and the fifth dimension the patch index? What is the patch index?
I've run the following code:
Eigen::Tensor<double, 4> batch (2, 2, 10, 12); // column major order
Eigen::Tensor<double, 5> patches = batch.extract_image_patches(3, 3, 1, 1, Eigen::PADDING_VALID);    
std::cout << patches.dimensions();

which prints:
[2, 3, 3, 20, 12] 
So 2 channels (correct), 3 rows and cols in the patch (correct) but what do (20) and (12) represent? Also, where are the number of batches?
Thanks
Researched documentation and looked on SO

20 is just 2 * 10 (rows * cols). The last dimension is either time or batches, which you specified as 12..

@Botje - Thanks. The last dimension of batches (the input to the function) is 12 which I understand is the width of the channel?
